# Javascript Countdown Timer Repeat and Count total that repeat

Tags: javascript

I have javascript countdown timer from 25 -> 0.

```
var count=25;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
   }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count; // watch for spelling
 }
```

div HTML

```
<span id="timer">25</span>
```

Now I want the countdown is repeat automatically after wait 5 seconds then it start again from 25 -> 0. And I want to count how many times that countdown repeat. Is it possible for that?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try wrapping the entire code into a function (`countTimers()` in the example below) that runs every 30 seconds (5 seconds after each timer). Then, set a counter (`timersCount` in the example below) to count how many times that will run.

See the example below:

```js
var timersCount = 0, stopped = false, count, counter; // make count, counter global variables so buttons can access them
var timerCounter = setInterval(countTimers, 30000);
countTimers(); // run countTimers once to start
function timer() {
  count = count-1;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count;
  if(count <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }
}
function countTimers() {
  timersCount++;

  // as per request in the comments, you can set a timer counter as well:
  document.getElementById("totalcounter").innerHTML = timersCount;

  count = 25;
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

}

// button code:
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(timerCounter);
  clearInterval(counter);
  count = 25;
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count;
  timersCount = 0;
  document.getElementById("totalcounter").innerHTML = timersCount;
  stopped = true;
});
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(stopped)
    return;
  clearInterval(counter);
  stopped = true;
});
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(!stopped)
    return;
  stopped = false;
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(counter);
    timerCounter = setInterval(countTimers, 30000);
    countTimers();
  }, count*1000);
});
```

```html
Timer: <span id="timer">25</span><br>
Number of times run: <span id="totalcounter">1</span>

<br><br>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="start">Start (if stopped)</button>
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, can I set the counter (total how many times) into, example: <span id="totalcounter"><span> ?

Comment: @DavidAlwis Yeah, you can do it the same way as the other counter. I'll add an example.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the update. I tried your code but the function is not work. Countdown not function

Comment: @DavidAlwis It's working just fine for me... What exactly is the error you're getting? Does the example above work for you?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, sorry I do a mistake in code. Thank you for your help. Cheers

Comment: @DavidAlwis I'm glad I helped. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, last question. If you have time, is it possible to make the function pause, resume and reset countdown?

Comment: @DavidAlwis In short, to reset the countdown, simply set the counter back to 25 and run a `clearInterval()` on both `setInterval()` instances. To pause, you can run a `clearInterval()` on `count` and just resume it with `setInterval()` again (leave the counter as is). I'll provide a quick example

Comment: @DavidAlwis I added an example, but it's a little long and complex. Have fun!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, just tried. When stop then start again the count is not correct

Answer (score 2):

```
var count=25;
var counter = null;

// reset count and timer
function reset_timer()
{
    count = 25;
    counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
}

// init timer for first time
reset_timer();

function timer()
{
  count--;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
    clearInterval(counter);
    setTimeout(reset_timer, 5000);
    return;
   }

 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count; // watch for spelling
 }
```

setTimeout is a timer that runs one time and stop.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `Promises` to the countdown work and generate an infinite loop,
if for some reason you need to `stop/resume` your counter you can reject the Promise chain and have a `boolean` to control the state:

```js
let secondsCounter = 
    document.querySelector('#secondsCounter'),
    totalCount =
    document.querySelector('#totalCount'),
    ttc = 1,
    actualSecond = 25,
    isPaused = false,
    interval;

let countDown = time => new Promise( (rs, rj) =>   interval = setInterval( ()=>{
    if (isPaused) {
      return rj('Paused');
    }
    secondsCounter.textContent = --actualSecond;
    if (actualSecond == 0){
      actualSecond = time + 1;
      clearInterval(interval);
      rs();
    }
  }, 1000));

let loop = time => countDown(time).then( ()=>{
  totalCount.textContent = ++ttc;
  return Promise.resolve(null);
});

let infinite = () => loop(25)
  .then(infinite)
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));

let stop = () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  isPaused = true;
}

let resume = () => {
  console.log('Resumed');
  isPaused = false;
  loop(actualSecond).then(infinite);
}

let start_stop = () => isPaused ? 
  resume() : stop();

infinite();
```

```html
Seconds : <div id="secondsCounter">25</div>
Times   : <div id="totalCount">1</div>

<button onclick="start_stop()">Start/Stop</button>
```